# Controlling 9 servos with a Bluno board

Tags: arduino, power-supply, servo, robot

I'm trying to build a robot that requires 5 micro servos and 4 standard servos. The micro controller board I am using is a 'DFRobot Bluno' (compatible with Arduino software). The board gets power from a 7.4v Li-Po battery, which is enough to power the servos (and so the robot) for a good 10-15 minutes before needing to recharge it.

The original robot that i'm basing this on is a BQZum Core. The BQZum Core board has these 'triple pins' (see image) with ground, 5v, and signal that the servos can be easily plugged into. Having so many 5v and ground pins, this board has no issue in running all of the servos. Unfortunately I could not get my hands on one of these boards nor have I found one that matches my requirements (has to be <8x8cm and integrated bluetooth) and also has these 'triple pin rows'.

Since my Bluno board doesn't have the same 'triple pin rows' I am worried about the setup (see diagram) because all of the power to the servos comes from the 5v pin. Would this result in servo performance issues? And is it damaging to the board? If so, what's the best course of action? Using an external supply for the servos? Using a different micro controller board?

I am working in a really tight space and so I might not be able to fit in a separate power supply in the robot for the servos. Could it be an option to split the power supply? Part to the board and part to the servos?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Setup diagram
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aihJp.png

BQZumCore board
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNWBi.jpg

Comment: can't you power the servos from the battery directly?

Comment: Micro servos 3~6V 4.8V nom.

Comment: WHat is 5V current limit and load surge current?

Comment: I could power the servos from the battery directly but I also need to power the micro controller board. Maybe I could split the battery to power them each individually? But i'm not sure if that would work.